# How can I disable Pushy in Capacitor using Ionic Toggle?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, pushy

Is there a way to disable Pushy, in Capacitor, using Ionic Toggle? There are no function in the pushy documentation: https://pushy.me/docs/additional-platforms/capacitor

The goal is to have a toggle switch for enabling/disabling Pushy.

Something similar this?

```
async pushyToggle() {
   if (isPush == true) {
     await enablePushy();
   }
   else if () {
     await disablePushy();
   }
}
```

I think I might be doing it all wrong. Need help. Thanks!

Comment: If there is no documentation on it then it does not support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Pushy.unregister()` to stop the device from receiving notifications, as mentioned in the [Pushy Android SDK docs](https://pushy.me/docs/sdk/android) and [Pushy iOS SDK docs](https://pushy.me/docs/sdk/ios). This method is also supported in the [Pushy Cordova SDK](https://github.com/pushy/pushy-cordova) which Capacitor support depends on.

Invoke this method to unregister the device from receiving notifications. Calling `Pushy.register()` on the device in the future will (in most cases) restore the device token which was previously assigned to the device.

**Full disclosure:** I work at Pushy.

Comment: Hi @Elad this certainly work thanks. I have another issue on pushy though. Please have a look:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75674984/pushy-not-working-after-i-build-a-signed-in-release-debug-apk-in-android-studio